# Unexpected result by MySQL Optimizer for identical queries?

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Following query is working like expected and uses index
Query takes 0,0481 sec

```
SELECT 
    geodb_locations.name, 
    geodb_locations.name_url,
    COUNT(user.uid) AS useranzahl 
FROM 
    user 
LEFT JOIN
    geodb_locations ON geodb_locations.id=user.plz
WHERE
    user.freigeben=1 AND
    geodb_locations.adm0='AT'
GROUP BY user.plz
ORDER BY useranzahl DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Explain
[image]

If only country locale is changed within the query from AT to DE
Query takes about 2.5 sec and does not use index

```
SELECT 
    geodb_locations.name, 
    geodb_locations.name_url,
    COUNT(user.uid) AS useranzahl 
FROM 
    user 
LEFT JOIN
    geodb_locations ON geodb_locations.id=user.plz
WHERE
    user.freigeben=1 AND
    geodb_locations.adm0='DE'
GROUP BY user.plz
ORDER BY useranzahl DESC
LIMIT 25
```

Explain
[image]

Why is index not used by the optimizer of second query and how to improve the query.
2.5 sec are to long ..

Comment: Note that you'd typically include in a GROUP BY clause all non-aggregated columns mentioned in the SELECT clause.

Comment: Also, these are INNER JOINs

Comment: Thanks, but "INNER JOIN" and "GROUP BY user.plz, geodb_locations.name, geodb_locations.name_url" has no impact on query performance .. still 2.5 sec

Comment: Maybe not, but at least you now have a valid query. So that's a better place from which to begin

Comment: I'm with Strawberry -- those were the first two things that I worried about, followed by the lack of `COUNT(*)` and the interchangeability of `geodb_locations.id` and `user.plz`.

Answer (score 0):

If `u.uid` cannot be `NULL`, use `COUNT(*)` instead of `COUNT(u.uid)`.

As already pointed out, remove `LEFT`.

Add these indexes:

```
user:  (freigeben, plz)
geodb_locations:  (adm0, name_url, name)
```

As for why the `EXPLAIN` changed, ...  It is quite normal (but somewhat rare) for the distribution of the constants to determine what order the tables are touched (Austria is less common than Germany?) or which index to use.

Regardless of optimizations, this query will have to scan a lot more rows for DE than for AT; this has to happen before the sort (`ORDER BY`) and `LIMIT`.

Two things prevent much optimization:

- The `WHERE` references both tables.
- The `ORDER BY` depends on a computed value.